# Config apc in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, optimization, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

i need to maximize **performance** in a **zend framework 2 + doctrine 3 project** , the application is **slow** so i've woked in enabling the memcache for some queries  , i've also enabled the cache for the config files ... but the application stills slow so searching in the net i found some articles talking about performing zf2 project and mentioning **apc** as a way to make the application not so slow , so i've installed **apc**, but i can't find a way to configure how to enable **apc** in **zend framework 2**?

Answer (score 0):

APC is a PHP extension, it's not something you need to enable within individual applications unless you're using it for userland caching as well (which I assume you are not, since you mentioned memcache). You can check if it's working by firing up a phpinfo page and seeing if you have an APC section.

If you have PHP 5.5 or above, you don't need (and shouldn't use) APC, as PHP comes with its own (better) opcache.

I'd suggest you benchmark your application using something like XDebug to find out what is causing the slowness. This should give you a better idea what you need to improve.

Comment: thanks for your reply , i appreciate that . However , i'm using xdebug with webgrind  and i use this slides : http://www.shawnstratton.info/slides/zendcon/ to figure out where is the wrong... but it's not so clear.For the apc yeah i did add the .dll needed and i can have it's section in phpinfo() ... i guess i need a tuto to understand more about the cache ( memcache , apc) and about performance if you have any link it would be great , or any explaination ... thanks